# Handling logout with Meteor and React

Tags: reactjs, meteor

With ReactRouter I make sure a user is redirected to the login component if he's not authenticated when accessing a route that needs an authentication:

```
<Route path="/place/:place_id" component={ Place } onEnter={ authenticate }/>
```

How to redirect the user to the authenticate component again when the user sign out, preferably without the need to call a route explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the logout is happening on an onClick or some description,

```
const handleLogout = () => Meteor.logout(() => browserHistory.push('/login'));
```

I am using react-router here, so ymmv. This resource might also help: https://github.com/themeteorchef/base